# Spring Security: How do I enable custom expression result type support?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot application I'm using the `@PreAuthorize` annotation in my controller methods to make them authorized. The expressions use simple `boolean`-returning methods, like this:

```java
@ResponseStatus(OK)
@PreAuthorize("@auth.authentication.mayReadMe(principal)")
public UserDto readMe() {
    ...
```

The `mayReadMe(...)` method simply returns a boolean value, however it uses ternary logic under the hood and just converts a special enum to `boolean`:

```java
boolean mayReadMe(@Nonnull UserDetails principal);
```

Now let's say I want to rework the authorization components and let the method return the enum:

```
@Nonnull
foo.bar.FooBarEnum mayReadMe(@Nonnull final UserDetails principal);
```

However, I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '@primaryAuth.authentication.mayReadMe(principal)'
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:15)
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.before(ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.java:44)
    at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:25)
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:62)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1001E:(pos 0): Type conversion problem, cannot convert from @javax.annotation.Nonnull foo.bar.FooBarEnum to java.lang.Boolean
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.convertValue(StandardTypeConverter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.ExpressionUtils.convertTypedValue(ExpressionUtils.java:53)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:301)
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:11)
    ... 113 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [@javax.annotation.Nonnull foo.bar.FooBarEnum] to type [java.lang.Boolean]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:313)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.convertValue(StandardTypeConverter.java:74)
    ... 116 common frames omitted
```

The exception message is really clear, but I can't inject my custom converter in any way. What I've tried so far:

- Registering custom converters via `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.addFormatters(FormatterRegistry)` (both `Converter` and `GenericConverter`)
- `Bean`-ining a custom `ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice` (but it shouldn't work as far as I understand)
- ... and a few other ways I can't recall after spending a few hours unfortunately.

How do I inject a custom type converter so the `@PreAuthorization` expressions could be aware of the `foo.bar.FooBarEnum` as the returning type?

---

### Edit 1

Why do I need a custom type to be returned, and not a boolean. I'm also writing a simple REST API self-describing subsystem, just a simple `GET /api` endpoint to return a list of endpoints and so on. This list consists of a certain objects describing API end point, HTTP method, incoming and outgoing DTOs, and the last thing I'm trying to add to the definition object is an endpoint authorization policy expression. Note that it's not a good idea to return the `@PreAuthorize` string expression (I mean a raw string), but it might be good to return a *custom* object describing the authorization rules. What I want the most is returning an object like:

```java
public final class AuthorizationExpression
    implements BooleanSupplier {
    ...
    public IExpression toExpression() {
    ...
}
```

where `BooleanSupplier` is expected to be used in the converter I'm trying to inject in order to satisfy the authorization needs -- just return `true` or `false`, and where `IExpression` is expected to be `toString`-ed in the `GET /api` handler using the Spring expression evaluator. Hence the `mayReadMe` signature might be as follows:

```java
AuthorizationExpression mayReadMe(...)
```

so I could use `AuthorizationExpression` up to a certain use case. The `FooBarEnum` is just a simplification for the original question prior to the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I only need to tune the `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` instance. Let's assume the net two classes as library ones:

```java
public abstract class CustomTypesGlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration
        extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    protected abstract ApplicationContext applicationContext();

    protected abstract ConversionService conversionService();

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        final ApplicationContext applicationContext = applicationContext();
        final TypeConverter typeConverter = new StandardTypeConverter(conversionService());
        final DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
            @Override
            public StandardEvaluationContext createEvaluationContextInternal(final Authentication authentication, final MethodInvocation methodInvocation) {
                final StandardEvaluationContext decoratedStandardEvaluationContext = super.createEvaluationContextInternal(authentication, methodInvocation);
                return new ForwardingStandardEvaluationContext() {
                    @Override
                    protected StandardEvaluationContext standardEvaluationContext() {
                        return decoratedStandardEvaluationContext;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public TypeConverter getTypeConverter() {
                        return typeConverter;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        handler.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return handler;
    }

}
```

where `ForwardingStandardEvaluationContext` is a simple forwarding decorator to decorate an instance of `StandardEvaluationContext` because the latter is `ConversionService`-aware:

```java
public abstract class ForwardingStandardEvaluationContext
        extends StandardEvaluationContext {

    protected abstract StandardEvaluationContext standardEvaluationContext();

    @Override public void setRootObject(final Object rootObject, final TypeDescriptor typeDescriptor) { standardEvaluationContext().setRootObject(rootObject, typeDescriptor); }
    @Override public void setRootObject(final Object rootObject) { standardEvaluationContext().setRootObject(rootObject); }
    @Override public TypedValue getRootObject() { return standardEvaluationContext().getRootObject(); }
    @Override public void addConstructorResolver(final ConstructorResolver resolver) { standardEvaluationContext().addConstructorResolver(resolver); }
    @Override public boolean removeConstructorResolver(final ConstructorResolver resolver) { return standardEvaluationContext().removeConstructorResolver(resolver); }
    @Override public void setConstructorResolvers(final List<ConstructorResolver> constructorResolvers) { standardEvaluationContext().setConstructorResolvers(constructorResolvers); }
    @Override public List<ConstructorResolver> getConstructorResolvers() { return standardEvaluationContext().getConstructorResolvers(); }
    @Override public void addMethodResolver(final MethodResolver resolver) { standardEvaluationContext().addMethodResolver(resolver); }
    @Override public boolean removeMethodResolver(final MethodResolver methodResolver) { return standardEvaluationContext().removeMethodResolver(methodResolver); }
    @Override public void setMethodResolvers(final List<MethodResolver> methodResolvers) { standardEvaluationContext().setMethodResolvers(methodResolvers); }
    @Override public List<MethodResolver> getMethodResolvers() { return standardEvaluationContext().getMethodResolvers(); }
    @Override public void setBeanResolver(final BeanResolver beanResolver) { standardEvaluationContext().setBeanResolver(beanResolver); }
    @Override public BeanResolver getBeanResolver() { return standardEvaluationContext().getBeanResolver(); }
    @Override public void addPropertyAccessor(final PropertyAccessor accessor) { standardEvaluationContext().addPropertyAccessor(accessor); }
    @Override public boolean removePropertyAccessor(final PropertyAccessor accessor) { return standardEvaluationContext().removePropertyAccessor(accessor); }
    @Override public void setPropertyAccessors(final List<PropertyAccessor> propertyAccessors) { standardEvaluationContext().setPropertyAccessors(propertyAccessors); }
    @Override public List<PropertyAccessor> getPropertyAccessors() { return standardEvaluationContext().getPropertyAccessors(); }
    @Override public void setTypeLocator(final TypeLocator typeLocator) { standardEvaluationContext().setTypeLocator(typeLocator); }
    @Override public TypeLocator getTypeLocator() { return standardEvaluationContext().getTypeLocator(); }
    @Override public void setTypeConverter(final TypeConverter typeConverter) { standardEvaluationContext().setTypeConverter(typeConverter); }
    @Override public TypeConverter getTypeConverter() { return standardEvaluationContext().getTypeConverter(); }
    @Override public void setTypeComparator(final TypeComparator typeComparator) { standardEvaluationContext().setTypeComparator(typeComparator); }
    @Override public TypeComparator getTypeComparator() { return standardEvaluationContext().getTypeComparator(); }
    @Override public void setOperatorOverloader(final OperatorOverloader operatorOverloader) { standardEvaluationContext().setOperatorOverloader(operatorOverloader); }
    @Override public OperatorOverloader getOperatorOverloader() { return standardEvaluationContext().getOperatorOverloader(); }
    @Override public void setVariable(final String name, final Object value) { standardEvaluationContext().setVariable(name, value); }
    @Override public void setVariables(final Map<String, Object> variables) { standardEvaluationContext().setVariables(variables); }
    @Override public void registerFunction(final String name, final Method method) { standardEvaluationContext().registerFunction(name, method); }
    @Override public Object lookupVariable(final String name) { return standardEvaluationContext().lookupVariable(name); }
    @Override public void registerMethodFilter(final Class<?> type, final MethodFilter filter) throws IllegalStateException { standardEvaluationContext().registerMethodFilter(type, filter); }

}
```

And then a couple application classes:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = false)
class SecurityConfiguration
        extends CustomTypesGlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private final ConversionService conversionService;

    public SecurityConfiguration(
            @Autowired final ApplicationContext applicationContext,
            @Autowired final ConversionService conversionService
    ) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.conversionService = conversionService;
    }

    @Override
    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected ConversionService conversionService() {
        return conversionService;
    }

}
```

And finally the conversion service configuration:

```
@Configuration
class ConversionConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConversionService conversionService() {
        final DefaultConversionService conversionService = new DefaultConversionService();
        conversionService.addConverter(FooBar.class, Boolean.class, FooBar::mayProceed);
        return conversionService;
    }

}
```

The code above makes `@PreAuthorize` to understand `FooBar`-returning expressions.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion, let your enum implement the conversion method:

```java
public enum FooBarEnum {

    // previous code

    public boolean booleanValue() {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

And change your annotation:

```
@PreAuthorize("@auth.authentication.mayReadMe(principal).booleanValue()")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking of this too, but I cannot use it for several reasons. I have just updated the question, please see "Edit 1".